# Should I engine features from coordinates (positional data)?

Tags: regression, feature-engineering

I am trying to do a regression on housing price (price/m^2). Apart from the lat and lng of the property, I also have city_code, district_id, street_id.

I am thinking whether I should remove city_code, district_id and street_id since those information should be contained in lat and lng. (Plus I got some missing value in district_id and street_id).

The other side of the question is should I engine other features out of lat and lng, for example, proximity to school, hospital,number of bus routes, etc. If lat and lng already contain all information of the neighborhood, will there be no value added by engineering those features?

Comment: In what sense do the coordinates (lat, lon) "contain all information of the neighborhood"?  For instance, suppose I gave you a coordinate: what could you tell me about the schools in its neighborhood, *without referring to any other information?*

Comment: @whuber you have the point! I was thinking, even without telling the models about the location of schools, bus route, etc, the model will know for a certain location, the price will be higher/lower because those additional features are derived from locations. But by including more information like school and bus route, we can explain the reasons why for a certain location, the price is higher/lower.